# How to run the same scripted pipeline multiple times in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I went over the internet to find out a way to run the same pipeline multiple times but have not found an answer.
Basically, the pipeline has 5 stages and I want this pipeline to run 5 times, each iteration of the pipeline will execute the stages in the same order in the code.

```
node{

def build_ok = true
    

    try{
    stage('#1 SoftSync 4.5.1 CPU Usage Test') {
          build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_CPU_Usage_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_CPU_Usage_Test.robot')]
    }
    } catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString()  
    }
    
    
    try{
    stage ('#2 SoftSync 4.5.1 Improvments to system time management Test '){
        build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Improvments_To_System_TimeManagement_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Improvments_to_system_time_management.robot')]
    }
    }catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString() 
    }
    
    try {
    stage ('#3 SoftSync 4.5.1 Telematics and statistics Test'){
       build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Telematics_and_statistics_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Telementry_and_Statistics.robot')]
    }
    }catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString() 
    }

    //try{
      //stage ('#4 SoftSync 4.5.1 PTP Profiles Slave Lock Test'){
        build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_PTP_Profiles_SlaveLock_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/PTP_Bundle/SoftSync_PTP_Lock_validation.robot')]
    //} 
    //}catch(e) {
    //    build_ok = false
    //    echo e.toString() 
    //}


    try{
      stage ('#5 SoftSync 4.5.1 Alarms Test'){
       build job: 'SoftSync_4.5.1_Alarms_Test', parameters: [string(name: 'LOG_LEVEL', value: 'debug'), string(name: 'FILE_PATH', value: 'TLV_SoftSync/Management_Bundle/SoftSync_Alarms_Test.robot')]
    }
    }catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString() 
    }
    

    
    
if(build_ok) {
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
} else {
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
}


post{
    always{
        junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: '/var/lib/jenkins/output/*.xml'
    }
}
}
```

I have seen some usages with arrays and .each function but all for parallel usages witch is not help full in my case...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your stages with a loop. Something like below.

```
node {
    def itrList = ["Run1", "Run2", "Run3"]
    itrList.each { val ->
            
        def build_ok = true
        try {
            stage("#1 SoftSync 4.5.1 CPU Usage Test with $val") {
                echo "111111"
            }
        } catch (e) {
            build_ok = false
            echo e.toString()
        }

        try {
            stage("#2 SoftSync 4.5.1 Improvments to system time management Test  with $val") {
                echo "22222222222"
            }
        } catch (e) {
            build_ok = false
            echo e.toString()
        }

        if (build_ok) {
            currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
        } else {
            currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        }
    }
}
```